# multiple iterations of the same div?

Tags: javascript, html, iteration

So I have a menu on a screen where there are several identical boxes - the only difference is that the boxes are numbered differently.

```
<div id="1">
    <select name="option1">
        <option value="1">foo</option>
        <option value="2">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <select name="option2">
        <option value="1">foo</option>
        <option value="2">bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Each div is 900~ lines of code, and whenever I change I have to change each div - is writing a for loop and using document.write the best way to accomplish writing the div only once (and reduce file size)?

```
var divCode

for (var i=1; i < 7; i++){
 divCode +='
   <div id="'+i+'">
   <select name="option'+i+'">
   <option value="1">foo</option>
   <option value="2">bar</option>
   </select>
   </div>'
}
document.write('divCode')
```

Or is there is a better method in javascript? I imagine there is one, considering that writing 900 lines of concatenated string code is not fun (or efficient).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in general by having several numbered, 900-line `<div>`s that are otherwise identical?

Comment: I am not sure which one is faster, using innerHTML to insert the text or document.write

Comment: Maybe you could use a javascript templating system, such as Mustache?

Comment: Are you by chance using MVC? If so, you can put your div in a partial view, then include the partial view in a parent view 4 times, passing the parameter you need to change in the model. You can refresh the parent view via ajax to refresh all 4 (or any number of) partial views at once. I can demonstrate with an example if you confirm you are using MVC.

Comment: Somebody once told me.. "If you're using `document.write()` you're more than likely wrong".

Comment: Don't quote `divCode` -- that will just write the string, not the HTML in its value.

Comment: Well, if we’re talking about the sample code’s failings, in addition to `'divCode'` you have multi-line string literals (a syntax error) and an initial value of `undefined`…

Comment: I assume you're not using a server-side scripting language like PHP to create your page. Then you would run the loop on the server.

Comment: @minitech: It's difficult to explain without showing the ACTUAL code - its a menu for a game where there are multiple participants.

Comment: @RUJordan InnerHTML would be the alternative? In either case, the question stands.

Comment: @paperfairy: Please do your best anyways! It doesn’t make sense as-is. Is this a JavaScript-based game? Is there a server side involved? What to the `<div>`s represent?

Comment: @mayabelle I'm not familiar with MVC, sorry.

Comment: @minitech It is a javascript calculator for a roleplaying game. This calculator calculates combat between characters. There can be up to six characters and combat is altered by numerous different variables (which is why its 900 lines of code). If the game changes in any way, I have to change all six divs, and obviously loading times would decrease if the page had 900 lines instead of 5400 lines.

Comment: @minitech It's all client-side.

Comment: for one, get those semicolons in there buddy!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a JavaScript templating engine like mustache to keep your code simple and maintainable.

Here an example (which also uses jQuery besides mustache):
HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template_divs">
    {{#divs}}
    <div id="{{id}}">
        Hallo my name is {{name}}!
    </div>
    {{/divs}}
</script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var someDivs = {divs: [{id: 1, name: "Tom"},{id: 2, name: "Bob"},{id: 3, name: "Earl"}]};

var parsed = Mustache.render($('#template_divs').html(), someDivs);

$('#container').html(parsed);
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2gYCz/

Comment: definitely the correct answer. There is also Tim Templates. Very very small code base - ~200 bytes minified & gzipped! https://github.com/premasagar/tim

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree that using a Javascript Library to template would be ideal for the described issue. However, I would like to present an alternative using html and Javascript with no libraries. What I would do is to create a template in html not visible, something like this:

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="template"> <div class="someDiv" style="display:none;overflow: hidden;">Some Div</div> </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var item =document.querySelector(".someDiv" );
        var parent = document.querySelector(".template");
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++){
            item = item.cloneNode(true);
            item.setAttribute("id","newDemo"+i);
            item.setAttribute("style","");
            parent.appendChild( item );
        }
```

Using Javascript I would clone the item and set properties with the dynamic values.

Comment: Still it would be good practice to store the template html inside a `<script>` tag (with some type that does not get parsed) so the browser does not parse the html inside it.